# Security of AWS ALB DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I have set up the AWS ALB for the microservices on ECS, and set up an API gateway in front of AWS ALB for the public use. However, ALB has its own public DNS, will it be a security concern? If yes, any suggestion on it?

Comment: What exact security concern/threat/vector are you referring to?

Comment: @RodrigoM I'm not an expert for cybersecurity. But I wonder whether the following issues may happen if someone knows the ALB public DNS:
1. DDoS attack
2. Unauthorized access to the ALB public DNS to directly access the data bc from API gateway I can always use API key or authentication to only allow certain services to use the APIs.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you setup an internal application load balancer and then you are using API gateway to route the traffic to the ALB.
If that is the case then see this doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html
"The nodes of an internal load balancer have only private IP addresses. The DNS name of an internal load balancer is publicly resolvable to the private IP addresses of the nodes. Therefore, internal load balancers can only route requests from clients with access to the VPC for the load balancer."
Hope that answers your question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to attach your internet facing load balancer with the services which are not public serving.

You may use internal-load balancer to route request and the private hosted zone, which will work inside VPC and you don't have to route through the whole internet in order to route request between your services. You can take advantage of Host-Based routing in this case.

It will be a slow time-consuming process which may add up in your time latency. [1]

You can use ECS service load balancing if you are using awsvpc as your network while spinning up the service. In this way, you don't even need a load balancer to attach with any service. It will take care of your task container IP to add as an A record in the hosted zone associated with a service name. [2]

> Ref:
>   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html
>   [1]
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/how-elastic-load-balancing-works.html
>   [2]